# What are some good laptops for AutoCAD?

Tags: laptop

I’m looking to purchase a decently powerful laptop to use for AutoCAD.

There are a few specs that I require:

- 2.5 GHz quad core CPU
- 8 GB of RAM
- 256 GB SSD
- Good battery
- Good design (preferably on the thinner side)

13, 15 inch. Definitely not 17. Preferably under $1.5k. I’ve been looking at the Huawei Matebook 13 and HP Spectre. Not sure which one to get.

The Dell XPS 13 looks really good spec wise but I’m not quite settled on the design and price.

Comment: While you might be right that those specs match the minimum specs for AutoCAD, they are far from the recommended ones: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/System-requirements-for-AutoCAD-2019-including-Specialized-Toolsets.html. Another thing - which most of the small ones you meeantioned do not have is a dedicated GPU

Comment: How much do you care about a nice screen? Do you have a specific weight limit? Purely AutoCAD, or other CAD programs as well? My instinct given your preference for a thinner design and [AutoCAD's general indifference to professional GPUs](https://youtu.be/CAVqIOITdmM?t=8m55s) is probably a light gaming notebook, but that could depend.

Comment: OK, GiB is not often used for RAM, but it remains stupid that the 8 GB of RAM doesn't fit into the 256 GB of SSD 32 times.

Answer (score 1):

If you are professional user of autocad then you need to look at professional mobile workstation like Dell Precision or Hp Zbook

Answer (score 0):

## [HP Spectre X360](https://store.hp.com/us/en/ConfigureView?catalogId=10051&langId=-1&storeId=10151&urlLangId=&catEntryId=3074457345619013336&quantity=1&color=dark%20ash%20silver)

**Configuration: $1199.99**

- **Size**: 13.3 inch screen, 0.57 inches thick
- **CPU**: i7-8565U. 4 cores, 8 threads. 1.8 - 4Ghz clock speed.
- **Memory**: 16GB
- **SSD**: 256GB NVMe
- **Battery life**: [12 hours, 7 minutes](https://www.laptopmag.com/reviews/laptops/hp-spectre-x360-13-inch-2019)